# Matrix norm $|||A|||_{2}=\max_{\lVert x \rVert_{2}=\lVert y \rVert_{2}=1}\lVert y^{*}Ax\rVert_{2}$

Tags: matrices

We know that $|||A|||_{2}=\max_{\lVert x \rVert_{2}=1}\lVert x^{*}Ax\rVert_{2}$.
I have two questions about it.

1. How can we prove 
   $$|||A|||_{2}=\max_{\lVert x \rVert_{2}=\lVert y \rVert_{2}=1}\lVert y^{*}Ax\rVert_{2}?$$
2. Why do we add an extra a variable $y$ in this equality? Isn't $|||A|||_{2}=\max_{\lVert x \rVert_{2}=1}\lVert Ax\rVert_{2}$ perfect enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that in your definition, assuming the usual that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ an $n\times1$, $x^*Ax$ is a number. So your definition would be
$$
\|A\|=\max\{|x^*Ax|:\ x^*x=1\}.
$$
Now, this is the [numerical radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHZJm.jpg) of $A$ and not the operator norm (though they are equivalent as norms); the operator norm is defined as
$$\tag{1}
\|A\|=\max\{\|Ax\|_2:\ x^*x=1\}=\max\{(x^*A^*Ax)^{1/2}:\ x^*x=1\}.
$$
The operator norm and the numerical radius agree for normal matrices, but not in general. For example, 
$$\tag{2}
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
satisfies $|x^*Ax|\leq1/2$ for all $x\in \mathbb C^2$, while $\|A\|=1$.

Regarding your question, it is not true that
$$
\max\{|x^*Ax|:\ x^*x=1\}=\max\{|y^*Ax|:\ x^*x=y^*y=1\}
$$
in general. 
This can be seen to fail for $A$ in the example $(2)$, where the number on the left is $1/2$, and the number on the right is $1$.

What is true is that 
$$\tag{3}
\|A\|=\max\{|y^*Ax|:\ x^*x=y^*y=1\}.
$$
The inequality $\geq$ is a direct consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz, and the inequality $\leq$ can be seen by considering the case where $y=Ax/\|Ax\|_2$.

Also true is that for selfadjoint $A$, 
$$
\|A\|=\max\{|x^*Ax|:\ x^*x=1\}=\max\{|y^*Ax|:\ x^*x=y^*y=1\}.
$$
The proof of this is not hard, but not trivial either: below is the one from Conway: [image: Page 34 in Conway's Functional Analysis]

Finally, regarding your question 2). Think of the operator norm defined in $(1)$ and try to prove the triangle inequality. It is not impossible by any means, but not trivial either. On the other hand, it is trivial to prove it using $(3)$. The point is that in $(1)$ you are using a quadratic form, while in $(3)$ you are using a bilinear one.